# Windows EC2 => snapshot => AMI => new EC2 doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I am very new to AWS. I had a perfectly running Windows Server EC2 on **t2.micro**. IIS is working perfectly and I can get its HTML using a web browser. I can RDP into it.

I then stopped it, created a snapshot from its only EBS volume.

I then created an AMI from the snapshot.

I then launched the AMI. What is interesting is **t2.micro** is not available. Only **t1.micro** and **m3.medium** onward are available. When I tried to launch, it warns me that port 22 is not turned on so I can't remote into it. The instance status check says "insufficient data". When I clicked the "Connect" button, it asks me to use putty. So it seems to think that the instance is a Linux instance. But I have redone this whole process five times and under no circumstance I ever chose Linux.

If I skip the snapshot, and directly create an AMI from the EC2 instance and launch it, **t2.micro** is available, and the new instance works.

Why can't I create an AMI from snapshot, if AWS provides such functionality?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447504/how-to-create-a-windows-instance-from-snapshot-in-aws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot is a backup of your data.

AMI is snapshot of your system.It contains the bootable information like 
the architecture, kernel, block device mappings ,instance type etc. , so that it will have some information prior to instance launch.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create an AMI image of a Windows-based EC2 instance from an EBS snapshot. That process:

```
EC2 instance -> EBS snapshot -> AMI image -> EC2 instance
```

only works for Linux instances.

To create a working AMI image from a Windows EC2 instance, you must use the "Create Image" function from the source EC2 instance directly:

- Via AWS Management Console: `Actions -> Image -> Create Image`
- Via API: `ec2:CreateImage`
- Via CLI: `aws ec2 create-image`